# Accessing On Premise Api Through Azure Proxy with Azure Directory Enabled

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-application-proxy

I'm attempting to expose my on-premise APIs with Azure Application Proxy.

I've successfully configured it to work with the Pre-Authentication set to *Passthrough*. When I change the Pre-Authentication to *Azure Active Directory*  I can access the endpoint successfully via a browser. However, when I try calling the on-premise endpoint from code I receive the HTML for the Microsoft Sign-In page. A successful request will return a JSON Response.

I'm following a Microsoft article: [Secure access to on-premise APIs with Azure AD Application Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-secure-api-access#:%7E:text=Secure%20access%20to%20on-premises%20APIs%20with%20Azure%20AD,...%205%20Configure%20the%20native%20app%20code.%20)

Via an [Azure Docs defect](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/61446), I learned that I have to use "http://localhost" as a value for the RedirectUri and configure my client app as a "Mobile and desktop applications" platform.

Here is my code:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Successfully_authenticate_but_cant_access_the_proxy()
{
    // Acquire Access Token from AAD for Proxy Application
    var clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create("b510069b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9363xxxxxxxx") //Client Id for Client Application
        .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost") // This must be configured as a "Mobile and desktop applications" platform in the client application
        .WithTenantId("xxxxxx-d4cf-4xxx-xxxx-8dc72cbc00bd") //Not sure if this is needed.
        .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx-d4cf-4xxx-xxxx-8dc72cbc00bd")
        .Build();

    AuthenticationResult authResult;
    var accounts = await clientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
    var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

    IEnumerable<string> scopes = new string[] {"https://endpoints-xxx.msappproxy.net/user_impersonation"};

    try
    {
        authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
        authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();                
    }

    if (authResult != null)
    {
        //Use the Access Token to access the Proxy Application
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://endpoints-xxx.msappproxy.net");

        //Failing here. I'm receiving the HTML for the Sign-In page. I'm expecting a response with JSON.
        var responseValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Has anyone had any success accessing an on-premise endpoint via Azure Application Proxy with Azure Active Directory?

Comment: The error is in which line? `var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://endpoints-xxx.msappproxy.net");` or `var responseValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`? Can you see the content of the response when you debug it?

Comment: var responseValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); - it's the HTML for the sign-in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket with Microsoft and they were able to identify the issue.

The scopes needed a second slash '/' after the domain name:

```
IEnumerable<string> scopes = new string[] {"https://endpoints-xxx.msappproxy.net//user_impersonation"};
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Successfully_authenticate_but_cant_access_the_proxy()
{
    // Acquire Access Token from AAD for Proxy Application
    var clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create("b510069b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9363xxxxxxxx") //Client Id for Client Application
        .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost") // This must be configured as a "Mobile and desktop applications" platform in the client application
        .WithTenantId("xxxxxx-d4cf-4xxx-xxxx-8dc72cbc00bd") //Not sure if this is needed.
        .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx-d4cf-4xxx-xxxx-8dc72cbc00bd")
        .Build();

    AuthenticationResult authResult;
    var accounts = await clientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
    var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

    IEnumerable<string> scopes = new string[] {"https://endpoints-xxx.msappproxy.net//user_impersonation"};

    try
    {
        authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
        authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();                
    }

    if (authResult != null)
    {
        //Use the Access Token to access the Proxy Application
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://endpoints-xxx.msappproxy.net");

        //Failing here. I'm receiving the HTML for the Sign-In page. I'm expecting a response with JSON.
        var responseValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```